# Android+Maven "No resource identifier found for attribute 'installLocation' in package 'android'"

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

To add support to my android app for `installLocation` I upped my android level from 7 to 8 in my IDE (IntelliJ). The android app builds fine from IntelliJ.

We use maven though, and from Maven it fails to compile.

```
[ERROR] C:\dev\svnlocal\5x\android\AndroidManifest.xml:3: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'installLocation' in package 'android'
[ERROR] Error when generating sources.
```

I've also added

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```

I keep getting

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'installLocation' in package 'android'
```

I'd changed my dependency from

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>android</groupId>
  <artifactId>android</artifactId>
  <version>2.1_r1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>    
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
  <artifactId>android</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>    
</dependency>
```

But I was still getting this error message.

What's missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `mvn package -X` I could see that it was compiling with `android-sdk-windows/platforms/android-7` rather than `android-8`.

I finally tracked it down to

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <sdk>
      <platform>7</platform>
    </sdk>
```

Where `platform` should have been `<platform>8</platform>`

Answer (score 6):

The build target, however, needs to be updated to at least API Level 8 (Android 2.2), otherwise you’ll get the following error:

***`error: No resource identifier found for attribute ‘installLocation’ in package ‘android’`***

Change the build target by editing the project properties (right-click on the project in Eclipse), and choose a target with at least API Level 8: